# Linking css file inside to xslt file

Tags: css, pdf, xls, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP library to make a transform from a html + css file to pdf file. To do this process, I use several API's to reach to the final pdf. Firstly, I convert the html file to xml using TagSoup, then I transform xml to xsl-fo using xslt stylesheet for then and last step, I transform the xls-fo generated to pdf file. My problem comes when I view the pdf. I want to apply the same css styles as I apply in the html to the pdf too. I know if there are any way to link or include the css files in the xslt file when I try to do the transform to apply this styles on the final pdf.

I know this question is more theorical than a concrete practical case.
I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you got solution to this problem? I am also facing same issue. Please post answer if you have got solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find a solution for that. Good luck with your searching.